# RHEL6 Unable to download kickstart file

Tags: rhel, kickstart

In our lab we have a set of scripts that automatically configure a kickstart installation for RHEL5 on HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8. Based on data from several configuration files, it does the following steps:

1. mounts redhat dvd
2. modifies `isolinux.cfg` accordingly
3. creates `ks.cfg`
4. creates a bootdisk with the installation data (isolinux.cfg, ks.cfg, etc)
5. creates a http server with the bootdisk directory.
6. mounts the bootdisk through ILO (`/dev/scd1`)
7. installs RHEL5

Here is the line referring to the kickstart file location :

```
append initrd=initrd.img ks=hd:scd1:/isolinux/ks.cfg ksdevice=eth4
```

Everything works well for RHEL5, but there have been requests for RHEL6.

For RHEL6, everything seems to work OK until #7, where it returns the message `"unable to download kickstart file"`. I have commented some lines in the scripts, eliminating the installation part and leaving only the ILO mount part.

The bootdisk is mounted and accessible on `/dev/scd1`. The `ks.cfg` file is present there. I have also tested and the files from the Kickstart server are accessible with `wget`.

I have also tried accessing the `ks.cfg` file through http :

```
append initrd=initrd.img ks=http://<ip>:<port>/boot/isolinux/ks.cfg ksdevice=eth4
```

The above part did not work.

But what really vexes me is that RHEL5 works in the same conditions, but RHEL6 does not.

- Does `ks.cfg` have a different structure?
- Is the location of the `ks.cfg` file declared different from "hd:scd1:/isolinux/ks.cfg" on RHEL6?
- It seems strange that `isolinux.cfg` and `ks.cfg` are both present on the bootdisk, but only `isolinux.cfg` can be accessed.

I have been talking to redhat support for a week and they don't seem to know what is wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There were random syntax changes made to the `ks.cfg`, so some fiddling will likely be required to move from RHEL5 to RHEL6. Your issue sounds more network related, though, is the device really `eth4` or is RHEL6 instead generating some new device name for that NIC?

Comment: It is still eth4. Unless rhel replaces "scd1" with something else. I can confirm that the bootdisk is mounted, so it should not be a network problem at this point. Thank you for your response

Comment: I was investigating an unrelated ks issue here yesterday, and I noticed that there were examples using `ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg`, perhaps that'll work.

Comment: I have already tried using `cdrom`. The problem is that I have one physical cdrom (scd0) and the mounted image (scd1). Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem.

There seems to be a difference between RHEL5 and RHEL6 at the installation level.

RHEL5 will detect your physical cdrom and mount it on `/dev/scd0`, therefore the location of the mount will be `/dev/scd1`.
RHEL6 does not seem to do this, therefore the mount location will be `/dev/scd0`.

The correct way to declare the ks file location in a case like this is :

`append initrd=initrd.img ks=hd:scd0:/isolinux/ks.cfg ksdevice=eth4`

I hope someone will find this helpful in the future.

Comment: (you can also put the kickstart on the network)